# Is there a method to find out if a double is a real number in C#?

Tags: c#, math, double

So there is a method for NaN, but divide by zero creates infinity or negative infinity.

There is a method for Infinity (also positive infinite and negative infinity).

What I want is IsARealNumber function that returns true when the value is an expressible number.

Obviously I can write my own...

```
public bool IsARealNumber(double test)
{
    if (double.IsNaN(test)) return false;
    if (double.IsInfinity(test)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

but it doesn't seem like I should have to.

Comment: Seems pretty simple to me: return !double.IsNaN(test) && !double.IsInfinity(test);  // In the 3.5 framework you can even make it an extension method.

Comment: And now that you've written it, you'll never have to write it again :-)

Comment: doesn't it seem like it should be in there?
@GalacticCowboy, I've just noticed extension methods, how do I add that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add it as an extension method, it has to be a static member of a static class.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static bool IsARealNumber(this double test)
    {
        return !double.IsNaN(test) && !double.IsInfinity(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I right in assuming that you can only add these ExtensionMethods to objects, and not hang them off the class proper. Like double.IsNaN(double) is?

Comment: I believe that is correct.  It uses the type of the "this" parameter to determine what it applies to, and I doubt it's allowed to be static (so as to hang it off the class as a static member).

Answer (score 0):

[Double.IsFinite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.isfinite) can be used in modern .net